# Server uses 100% swap after fresh mysql installation

Tags: mysql, swap

I set up a new server with 220G RAM and Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.

After installing MySQL I changed the mysql config to:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 170G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 64
innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size = 134217728
innodb_log_file_size = 13G
collation_server = utf8_unicode_ci
character_set_server = utf8
sql-mode = "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,IGNORE_SPACE,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
user = mysql
datadir = /mnt/data/mysql/data
tmpdir = /mnt/data/mysql/tmp
key_buffer_size = 32M
thread_cache_size = 32
myisam-recover-options = BACKUP
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
slow_query_log = 1
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 2
log_bin = /mnt/data/mysql/log/mysql-bin.log
max_binlog_size = 2G
```

`/mnt/data` is a lvm partition with 400G.

I also installed *MySQL-Exporter* and *node-exporter*.
Before I have installed both exporters, the database import worked without any problem, but if want to import the database (ca. 150G uncompressed) now, the SWAP partition gets fully occupied, but the RAM is only used up to 85%.

Now I want to find out which process is responsible for the SWAP load.

How can I list how much swap each process uses?

If possible I want to keep the *swappiness* value at default.

**Edit:**

- Increased the SWAP to 64 GiB
- For the import I reduced the swappiness to 10
- After the import I set the swappiness to 50

The server has been running for 2 months and after the import I did not have any issues with the swap partition.

Comment: Is there an actual problem? Is performance poor? How much swap do you have?

Comment: "220G" -- That's an odd RAM size; please explain.

Comment: @RickJames My bad, it is 220Gi, so 7*32GB

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Not that I noticed it. But I am worried, that the performance will suddenly get poor or MySQL will crash. At the moment I only have 4G of swap. Only MySQL should run on the server and the swap partition should never be used. I could increase the swap partition (it's also a lvm partition), but ideally it will never be used.

Comment: Red Hat suggests SWAP size of 20% of RAM.  They have been successful enough, I would use their suggestion and make a 44G SWAP size.  And hope it is never used.

Comment: @Zystrix It's not really being used. It's just holding copies of dirty pages that haven't been modified recently that are also in RAM to make those pages of RAM discardable. The swap pages are discardable so long as the RAM pages aren't discardable, so the swap is in use but also available to change to another use if needed. The swap is currently being used to improve future performance but also available to be used for some other purpose if necessary.

Comment: @Zystrix  Additional DB information request, please. 
# cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
H) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @Zystrix Additional OS information request, please. 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
those-numbers-mean. 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @WilsonHauck AMD EPYC 7502P 32-Core Processor, 2*1TB NVME SSD in raid 1, [show global status](https://justpaste.it/cb0db), SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables: 431, [Show global variables](https://justpaste.it/c4spw), In the processlist were 4 entries, The backup script is separated in five scripts (1 base schema, 4 parallel executable scripts) , [SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name](https://justpaste.it/6jhjs)

Comment: @Zystrix Is your data storage SSD or NVME?  Any chance you can post any of the Additional OS information requested?  Your workload analysis is in process and could be more accurate with the OS information requested.  Thank You. Wilson

Comment: @Zystrix Your workload analysis will be completed after you post available Additional OS information.  How many items are listed for the MySQL SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; request in total, including sleeping items?

Answer (score 0):

I like `swappiness=1` for a mostly-MySQL server.

To help chase down the problem, lower `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.  Start with, say, 50GB.  After all, the buffer pool is a "cache".

When you "import" 150G of data, where does it live?  Perhaps the importer is loading the entire thing into RAM?  (That would be a poor design.)  Most compression/uncompression tools are quite happy to use only a small amount of RAM, yet can read/write very large files on disk.

**Remote backup**

If you backup is on host "backup" and you are reloading mysql on "db", consider running this on "backup":

```
zcat backup.sql.gz | mysql -h db ...
```

That eliminates needing to use disk space on "db" for the zip.  Also, it probably takes less *overall* time.  (I do not think it will affect "swap" usage on either machine.)

(Similarly, you could take the dump from "backup".)

Comment: If I want to import a full backup, I copy the compressed sql scripts to the server and then I import them like `zcat backup.sql.gz | mysql -u user -p[my_password] Database`
Edit: The compressed scripts are about 9G in size.

Comment: @Zystrix - Thanks.  I still can't explain "swap", but see what I added to my Answer.

Answer (score 0):

As simple solution, you can use [mysqltuner script](https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl)

Adjust dirty pages settings:

```
sysctl -a|grep vm.dirty
```

Same for shared memory settings:

```
sysctl -a|kernel.shm
```

I don't think that adjusting vm.swappiness will do a lot if your mysql instance is not using RAM and eats 100% of swap. Consider checking RAM usage with [ps_mem](https://github.com/pixelb/ps_mem) utility.

Reference: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/managing_monitoring_and_updating_the_kernel/adjusting-kernel-parameters-for-database-servers_managing-monitoring-and-updating-the-kernel

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like an aggressive swappiness configuration which I assume is high so the system starts swapping early.

A systems default value is high (60%) which depending on the environment may or may not be adequate.

You can check your current swappiness value using;

```
$ sysctl vm.swappiness
```

As you seem to be aggressively swapping, setting a lower value would be beneficial.

To change the value, you can use;

```
$ sysctl vm.swappiness=10
```

Comment: Bad advice. You *want* to write data to swap as early as possible. Right now, I/O is not precious. If you wait until I/O is precious to write data to swap, those I/Os will impact performance. Right now, they don't because the system is not I/O bound.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz What? Writing directly to swap as early as possible impacts IO negatively as the swap space uses storage meaning IO will immediately be impacted. The more aggressively a system swaps, the more IO hit you will get.

Comment: Writing directly to swap *before* I/O is under significant load means that you won't need to write it out later when I/O is precious because you are under load. At somen point in the future, this system may be under memory pressure. Do you want it to start writing the garbage it needs to evict from memory to swap then when it needs I/O to do the swapping? Better to do it before you need to because when you need to do it, you'll need to do lots of other things too.

Answer (score -1):

> Not that I noticed it. But I am worried, that the performance will suddenly get poor or MySQL will crash. At the moment I only have 4G of swap. Only MySQL should run on the server and the swap partition should never be used. I could increase the swap partition (it's also a lvm partition), but ideally it will never be used.

You have no issues. You *want* your swap to be used.

When you start up a machine, lots of processes run. Many of them will dirty memory that will *never* be used during the entire time the system remains running. For example, startup code faults in for programs that only startup once.

You *want* this junk to be written to swap for three reasons:

1. This stuff *cannot* be evicted from RAM without first writing it to swap. The system cannot *prove* it will never be accessed. Some of it, for example, may contain data needed to do a clean shutdown of some server process. Discarding the only copy would violate sanity guarantees.
2. If the system is ever under memory pressure, I/O will be precious. Performance will benefit from being able to evict this data from memory. But that can only be done by writing it to swap *first*. If it has already been written to swap, then there will be no need to write this data to swap when I/O is precious. So, by design, it is written to swap whenever it is "free" to do so.
3. By evicting this junk from memory, more RAM is useable as an I/O cache. This means *more* clean pages that are being re-used can be kept in memory, boosting performance.

Having 4GB of junk that can be evicted because it will likely never be used on a system with over 200GB of RAM is entirely reasonable and there is absolutely no reason to not want it to be written to swap.

Comment: How much swap would recommend? I'm a little bit confused, because at first (without mysql-exporter, node-exporter) the swap was barely used (0.1%).

Comment: @Zystrix It probably won't make much difference for a system like this. Likely the swap is just holding copies of data that's in memory anyway, so it's having no effect on performance. If the system never encounters memory pressure, it won't matter.